# How to retrieve Kindle eBook Lending Properties from the Amazon Product API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to retrieve the "Lending: Enabled/Disabled" property of a book item through their web service APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing.  It doesn't exist in the Product API currently, (as of the 2010-nov-01 version), but they do update it every month or so.  I'm hoping they add the capability soon!